# React Redux - mock useDispatch in a specific jest test

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I am trying to mock `useDispatch` in just a specific test. I am trying to mock like this:

`import * as reactRedux from "react-redux";`

`const useDispatchMock = jest.spyOn(reactRedux, "useDispatch");`

And still `useDispatch` is a normal function when running the test.

Using Jest `26.6.3`
React Redux `7.2.4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have done is correct , but you are just mocking the hook , but what we need is to mock the return value of the useDispatch function .

so you need to do this

```
 const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(reactRedux , 'useDispatch');
 const mockDispatchFn = jest.fn();
 useDispatchSpy.mockReturnValue(mockDispatchFn);
```

Now whenever there is a dispatch call made in your code , you can easily assert it using the `mockDispatchFn` . This is handy because now all the methods accessible on the jest mock function is now available on `mockDispatchFn` .

You can test the dispatched actions like

```
 expect(mockDispatchFn.mock.calls[0][0]).toMatchObject({ type: 'FETCHING_USER'});
```

Comment: That's great @Shyam
Thanks, for your reply

Comment: I get a can't redefine useDispatch error when trying this approach.

Answer (score 0):

What I prefer to do is create a mock store that goes into the provider

```
const store = {
   dispatch: jest.fn(),
   getState: () => mockState
};

render(<provider store={store}><Component {...props}/></provider>);
```

Further down in the assertion

```
expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(action);
```